# how to access IIS on VMware using PC name not IP

Tags: iphone, iis, networking, windows-7, vmware

I have a mac running Lion OS, and Windows 7 Ultimate installed on VMware Fusion
on my Windows machine, I have IIS running and I can access it from my mac browser using the IP address such as:

```
http://192.168.0.10
```

I am developing an iPhone app on xcode and connecting to IIS as a server to access MS Server DB for testing.

my problem is that I use my mac on many networks such as Work, Home, MiFi and others
every time I change the network the IP changes and every time I need to access IIS I need to update my server IP in my app.

even on my home netwrok or MiFi the IP is the same every time I connect (Dynamic)

I am thinking to access the IIS using the PC name on my windows 7 machine like this:

```
http://mypcname
```

to make easier to test without editing the IP every time.

Can anyone guide me how to do that? I did search around many sites and forums to figure it out with no success, maybe I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get anywhere on this?